# How do I open the locked door in Papunika Village?

Tags: evoland

In Papunika Village, near the well where you grow into an adult, there is a house with a locked door. Trying to enter shows a prompt:

> This door is locked. Maybe there’s something in there?

How do I open the locked door in Papunika Village?

[image: Locked door in Papunika Village]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can go behind the house to the right of it, then from there you can get into the locked house from the side~

- [Steam Discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/233470/discussions/0/828935361210142296/)

From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwT9d_2Vfpc), you can see you have to squeeze behind the house to the right of the well, and then enter the locked house from the wall on the right.